# Ansible playbook vars used as a mapping in tasks of same playbook

Tags: ansible

hello im trying to perform playbook job that looks like this:

```
- name: task of tasks
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    os_project: "supercoolproject_ng"
    os_tenant: "supercooltenant"
  tasks:
    - name: Create OS instance
      hosts: localhost
      vars:
        openstack:
          state: present
          locality: ng
          project: "{{ os_project }}"
          tenant: "{{ os_tenant }}"
          zone: row-r
          image: debian-10-amd64
          security_groups:
           - base
          server_group: wobani-servergroup
          instances:
            wobani01: t1.4c4r50d
      vars_files:
        - "{{ secrets_file }}"
      roles:
      - adm_openstack_deploy_instance
```

I expect to get it working like this:

```
 - name: Create OS instance
      hosts: localhost
      vars:
        openstack:
          state: present
          locality: ng
          project: supercoolproject_ng
          tenant: supercooltenant
```

Reality looks way worse than i expect:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/ansible/playbooks/deploy.yml': line 9, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - name: Create OS instance
      ^ here
```

I tryed to `debug: msg=` those vars i specified at the beginning and it work and shows those vars. But when i use it in `tasks > vars > "{{ os_project }}"` its failing.

The reason im trying it this way is that i repeat those `tasks` in multiple enviroment like locality and availability_zone (zone) and all of those tasks uses same name of tenant and same project name. Main reason was to make it easier to setup playbook for each different instances and not repeating tenant and project when written from scratch.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Why do you have a `hosts` definition under `tasks`? If you don't have any "tasks" to be performed, you can skip that section.

Answer (score 0):

YAML Syntax issue  - should be as follows

```
tasks:
- name: Create OS instance
```

Comment: Its best to quote a citation